# @DataJpaTest fails when using Eureka / Feign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have the the following Spring Boot application (using Eureka and Feign):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableRabbit
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class EventServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(EventServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the following test, annotated with @SpringJpaTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql = true)
public class EventRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testPersist() {
        this.entityManager.persist(new PhoneCall());
        List<Event> list = this.repository.findAll();

        assertEquals(1, list.size());
    }
}
```

While running the test I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient] found for dependency [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Full stacktrace [here](http://pastebin.com/upfyee0u)

Is there a way to solve this issue? I've seen that it is caused by @EnableFeignClients and @EnableDiscoveryClient annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my issue in the following way:

1. Added bootstrap.yml with the following contents:

   ```
   eureka:
     client:
       enabled: false
    spring:
      cloud:
        discovery:
          enabled: false
      config:
          enabled: false
   ```
2. I written a test configuration and referenced it in the test:

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = EventServiceApplicationTest.class)
   ```

   where EventServiceApplicationTest is:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
   public class EventServiceApplicationTest {}
   ```

I don't know if there is an easiest way but this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with **@EnableDiscoveryClient**.

I think that in such cases the easiest approach is put disabling information:

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

in `src/test/resources/application.[properties|yml]`. Then during tests running this configuration has higher priority than `src/main/resources/application.[properties|yml]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you're only intending to test your repository layer, you could filter out the unneeded beans from your `ApplicationContext` related to Feign, etc.

You can configure an *exclude* filter via the `excludeFilters` attribute of `@DataJpaTest`.

Details on filters can be found in the [Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters).

Another option would be to disable auto-configuration for Feign, etc. -- in which case you might find this answer useful: [Disable security for unit tests with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot/31183584#31183584)

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional links and a comment regarding disabling auto-configuration.

Comment: In fact @DataJpaTest automatically disables autoconfiguration, as stated  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) so disabling Feign, Eureka is not needed. I updated the post with the full stack trace. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: Anyway I managed to disable Eureka setting property `eureka.client.enabled=false` but I'm not able to disable Feign, event using `@DataJpaTest(showSql = true, excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = FeignAutoConfiguration.class))`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the following configuration in your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties={"eureka.client.enabled=false"})
@DataJpaTest(showSql = true)

public class BankRepositoryTest {

}
```