# @WithMockUser doesn't work in Integration Test - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am still getting Access Denied although my test method is annotated with @WithMockUser. Why this is not working in integration test? Everything is fine with test with @WebAppConfiguration and MockMvc.

**Test Class:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FileUploadIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private FileStorageService storageService;

    @Test
    public void classPathResourceTest() throws Exception {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/test/testFile.txt", getClass());
        assertThat(resource.exists(), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="tester",roles={"USER"})
    public void shouldUploadFile() throws Exception {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/test/testFile.txt", getClass());

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        map.add("file", resource);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/files", map, String.class);

//        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
        then(storageService).should().addFile((any(String.class)), any(MultipartFile.class));
    }
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public class FileUploadController {

    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;
    private AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController(FileStorageService fileUploadService, AuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade) {
        this.fileStorageService = fileUploadService;
        this.authenticationFacade = authenticationFacade;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UUID> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        UUID uuid = this.fileStorageService.addFile(authenticationFacade.getAuthentication().getName(), file);
        if (uuid != null) return ResponseEntity.ok(uuid);
        else return (ResponseEntity<UUID>) ResponseEntity.badRequest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solved it ? I have issues to get this to work as well

Comment: Unfortunately not ;/

Comment: do you use spring security oauth2?

Comment: Yes I used it - here is the repo of this module: https://github.com/MarcinMilewski/sqap-api

Comment: Hi ! I believe your PreAuthorize annotation is incorrect. `hasRole('ROLE_USER')` expects the authority "ROLE_ROLE_USER". Whereas in your test the `roles = "USER"` adds the authority "ROLE_USER".
You need to remove the "ROLE_" prefix from your PreAuthorize annotation

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't solve this with @WithMockUser.

You can try using the Profiles approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192495/3010484.