# How to disable security in integration tests in Spring Boot 2.2.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to disable `spring-security` in my integration test. I'm using `Spring boot 2.2.0` and in this version, I didn't find some methods to do it.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class}) // not working

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) // not working too.
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable security for unit tests with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot)

Comment: @Fateh no, these not working for me! I've read this post earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and I must have been banging our heads against the same thing at the same time it seems.

I was able to make `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)` do exactly what I wanted--disable all security for my unit tests.  However, it was immediately marked deprecated in my IDE because I was using Spring Boot 2.1.6.  I don't like using deprecated things so I tried and tried to get the `exclude` attribute to work, but it never did.

I was about to give up on it and suffer with the deprecation warning because at least my unit tests worked with it.

On a whim, I tried upgrading Spring Boot in my project from 2.1.6 to 2.2.2.  To my horror, the `secure` attribute was no longer deprecated--it was removed altogether!  I gave the unit test a spin with the attribute gone, but with the `exclude` attribute populated exactly as you show in your question and it worked!

## TL;DR? Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

you could play this game via profile

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = "IntegrationTest")
public class myTest {
```

Comment: it is not working for me. Can you give me more description of how to do it?

Comment: if you could the answer with **42 up vote** in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot