# How to disable SpringSecurity in Junit Test class using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

**I have created simple Rest Api service using spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE, I have just enabled Spring Security in the application. The JUnits are not working. I tried some of the ways to solve this issue but its not working.**

**Looking at references in books and online (including questions answered in Stack Overflow) I learned about two methods to disable security in tests:**

1. @WebMvcTest(value =MyController.class, secure=false)
2. @AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
3. @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

All these annotation i tried one by one on Test class but its not working.

1.@WebMvcTest(value =MyController.class, secure=false)

2.@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)

Both of these settings were identified in various Stack Overflow answers as being deprecated, but I tried them anyway.

Unfortunately, they didn't work. Apparently, in Version 2.2.1 of Spring Boot (the version I am using) secure isn't just deprecated, it is gone. Tests with the annotations using the "secure = false" parameter do not compile.
The code snippet looks like this:

```
 Code Snippet

package com.akarsh.controller;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootProj2Application.class,webEnvironment =SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SurveyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SurveyService surveyService;

    @Test
    public void retrieveDetailsForQuestion_Test() throws Exception {

        Question mockQuestion = new Question("Question1",
                "Largest Country in the World", "Russia", Arrays.asList(
                        "India", "Russia", "United States", "China"));

        Mockito.when(
                surveyService.retrieveQuestion(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito
                        .anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuestion);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
                "/surveys/Survey1/questions/Question1").accept(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        String expected = "{\"id\":\"Question1\",\"description\":\"Largest Country in the World\",\"correctAnswer\":\"Russia\",\"options\":[\"India\",\"Russia\",\"United States\",\"China\"]}";

        String actual=result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected,actual , false);


    }
```

\\

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Authentication : User-->Roles
    // Authorization : Role->Access 

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

         auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("{noop}secret").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("akarsh").password("{noop}ankit").roles("ADMIN","USER");

    }


     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

             http.httpBasic()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/surveys/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable();

        }



}
```

\
Getting following exception

```
Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your configuration.

2020-04-13 14:51:15.659 ERROR 5128 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@36902638] to prepare test instance [com.akarsh.controller.SurveyControllerTest@3eb8057c]
```

\\

```
@RestController
public class SurveyController {

    @Autowired
    SurveyService surveyService;

    @GetMapping("/surveys/{surveyId}/questions")
    public List<Question> retrieveQuestionForSrvey(@PathVariable String surveyId)
    {
        if(surveyId!=null)
        {
            return surveyService.retrieveQuestions(surveyId);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @GetMapping("/surveys/{surveyId}/questions/{questionId}")
    public Question retrieveQuestion(@PathVariable String surveyId,@PathVariable String questionId)
    {
        if(surveyId!=null)
        {
            return surveyService.retrieveQuestion(surveyId, questionId);
        }
        return null;

    }


    @PostMapping("/surveys/{surveyId}/questions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addQuestionForSrvey(@PathVariable String surveyId, @RequestBody Question question) {
        Question createdTodo = surveyService.addQuestion(surveyId, question);

        if (createdTodo == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(createdTodo.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable security for unit tests with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot)

Comment: @AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure= false) is not getting compiled in Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Why do you mean by "not getting compiled", be more precise, what is the exact error ? Then update your question with this information.

Comment: getting compile time error..."The attribute secure is undefined for the annotation type AutoConfigureMockMvc" when using @AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)